# slider with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

can u help me to adjust my code to make infinite slider? I tried on my own but when I changed conditions I got the problem with proper working.. just want to make it go from the last slide to first when the limit of slides is reached.. this is my code in JS

```
var nextBtn = $('.next_btn');
    var prevBtn = $('.prev_btn');
    var allSlides = $('.slide');
    var indexSlide = 0;

    $(allSlides[indexSlide]).addClass('visible');

    nextBtn.on('click', function(){
        if (indexSlide >= allSlides.length - 1) {
            indexSlide = allSlides.length - 1;
        } else {
            $(allSlides[indexSlide]).removeClass('visible');
            indexSlide++;
            $(allSlides[indexSlide]).addClass('visible');
        }
    })
    prevBtn.on('click', function(){
        if (indexSlide <=0) {
            indexSlide = 0;
        } else {
            $(allSlides[indexSlide]).removeClass('visible');
            indexSlide--;
            $(allSlides[indexSlide]).addClass('visible');
        }
    })
```

Comment: Better place your code online, together with html. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/ . This makes it easier for people to examine/debug it.

Comment: you can set `indexSlide = indexSlide % allSlides.length` when the user click the next/prev button to make the indexSlide 'wrap' around

Comment: not sure how to do it Nick since i found such clue somewhere but jsut failed to implement to my code.. I feel like i got some problem with adding and removing classes thats why some wierd stuff occures when i put indexSlide =0 in nextBtn condition and same story with prevBtn.. 

Marianos its hard for me to put on codeen or jsfiddle since Im trying to help my friend remotely and he gave me only JS code and he just said to me that it is not working as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. hide slide,
2. increment/decrement index
3. check whether it's in range (otherwise set proper value)
4. show new slide

```js
var nextBtn = $('.next_btn');
var prevBtn = $('.prev_btn');
var allSlides = $('.slide');
var indexSlide = 0;
var lastIndex = allSlides.length - 1;

$(allSlides[indexSlide]).addClass('visible');

nextBtn.on('click', function() {

  $(allSlides[indexSlide]).removeClass('visible');
  indexSlide++;
  if (indexSlide > lastIndex) {
    indexSlide = 0;
  }
  $(allSlides[indexSlide]).addClass('visible');

})
prevBtn.on('click', function() {

  $(allSlides[indexSlide]).removeClass('visible');
  indexSlide--;
  if (indexSlide < 0) {
    indexSlide = lastIndex;
  }
  $(allSlides[indexSlide]).addClass('visible');

})
```

```css
.slide {
  display: none;
}

.slide.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="prev_btn">Prev</button>
<button class="next_btn">Next</button>
<div class="slide">1</div>
<div class="slide">2</div>
<div class="slide">3</div>
```

Comment: thanks very much! Seems like Im stupid as hell.. I added also after if another else making my first div disappear.. Ehh I need to pay more attention and unfortunatelly after 3 months of coding I still make stupid mistakes.. need to focus more.. thanks for fast response) u guys are beasts :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, sometimes it happens :)